# change dns record for high number of email adresses

Tags: email, dns, office365

My new client is using Office 365 accounts. his company has couple of email adresses. i built him a new website and planning to host it on my webserver. 
i just want to make sure that i'm doing right:

1. changing the dns (mx etc) records on his existing url to my host service.
2. create "x" email adresses under his domain on my server (actually creating the same existing email adresses that they are using now).
3. change dns for **each** email adress with office365 wizard.

2 questions now:

1. am i right?
2. is there's any short way of doing that, am i forgetting something important, or this are the steps? 
   in other words: do i need to **create every email adress** on my host, and then enter **every adress's office365 wizard and change the records**?

Comment: How is building website in any way related to your clients email addresses?

Comment: @Dusan Bajic - it isn't??? if i change the dns records of the domain and link it to a different hosting service i don't need to update the mx enteries on office365 to link to my host???

Comment: No, MX records are just for handling emails and you probably don't want to touch them if you are not very sure about what you are doing, or your client will not be able to receive emails. If all you want is that new website is visible, you just need to add/modify `A` name record (so, if it is www.example.com, add `www A` record to point to IP address of your web server). Again, email addresses are unrelated to this, it is **very** common that one service provider (for example gmail) handles email service, and completely other service provides website hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in office 365 there is Admin account, and when updating dns records there it change all email accounts that connect to it.